# $ \frac {dy}{dx} \sin y = (1-x\cos y)\cos y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How may we solve the following differential equation, $$ \frac {dy}{dx} \sin y = (1-x\cos y)\cos y$$ ? (my progress concerning it is almost zero)

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to solve for y?

Comment: Hint: $\sin ydy=-d\cos y$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you proceed. Let

> $$ u(x)=\cos(y(x))\implies u'(x)=-\sin(y(x))y'(x) .$$

Substituting back in the ode gives

> $$ u'(x)=(xu(x)-1)u(x) \implies u'+u=x u^2 .$$

Now, this is [Bernoulli type ode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)

> $$ y'+ P(x)y = Q(x)y^n\,  $$

and there is a standard technique for solving it.

Comment: It is actually $1-xcosy$ , not $1-cosy$ , so you can not write $(1-u(x))$ , if i am not wrong , right ?

Comment: @SouvikDey: I see. Let me correct that.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal: $\frac {d(cosx)}{dx} = -sinx $ , right?

Comment: @SouvikDey:yes.